# How to know which Network Adapter is which Physical Port?

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, powershell

I have a Windows Server Core Server 2019 with 9 Network Adapters, split into 3 network cards:

```
[hypervisor05]: PS C:\Users\administrator\Documents> get-netadapter -physical | ft

Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------             ---------
Ethernet 5                Intel(R) 82580 Gigabit Network Con...#4      20 Up           00-00-00-00-00-00         1 Gbps
Ethernet 6                QLogic BCM5709C Gigabit Ethernet ...#49      19 Disconnected 00-00-00-00-00-00          0 bps
Ethernet 3                Intel(R) 82580 Gigabit Network Con...#3      18 Disconnected 00-00-00-00-00-00          0 bps
Ethernet 8                QLogic BCM5709C Gigabit Ethernet ...#50      14 Disconnected 00-00-00-00-00-00          0 bps
Ethernet 2                Intel(R) 82580 Gigabit Network Con...#2      11 Up           00-00-00-00-00-00         1 Gbps
Ethernet                  Intel(R) 82580 Gigabit Network Conne...       9 Up           00-00-00-00-00-00         1 Gbps
Ethernet 7                Intel(R) PRO/1000 PT Desktop Adapter          5 Up           00-00-00-00-00-00         1 Gbps
Ethernet 4                QLogic BCM5709C Gigabit Ethernet ...#47       4 Disconnected 00-00-00-00-00-00          0 bps
Ethernet 9                QLogic BCM5709C Gigabit Ethernet ...#48       3 Disconnected 00-00-00-00-00-00          0 bps
```

Is there any way for me to read from command line, which exact physical port this is on the machine? I have one DMZ Ethernet cable in the machine and 3 LAN cables and I need to know which one of the adapters listed above is the DMZ one.

There is a `PortNumber` Property, but this does not seem to be correct:

```
[hypervisor05]: PS C:\Users\administrator\Documents> get-netadapter -physical | select Name, PortNumber

Name       PortNumber
----       ----------
Ethernet 5          0
Ethernet 6          0
Ethernet 3          0
Ethernet 8          0
Ethernet 2          0
Ethernet            0
Ethernet 7          0
Ethernet 4          0
Ethernet 9          0
```

I know I can now simply disconnect the DMZ cable and see which Network Adapters status will change, however I'm curious if there is a completely virtual way to determine this. Preferably a way, that also tell me which physical port the disconnected adapters have.

Comment: You should be able tell this by the IP address assigned to the adapter.  Only four of your adapters have an address, you presumably know which address, is on the DMZ.  This is where labeling cables comes in handy

Comment: @Ramhound yes. This would be another way. However, I would also like to know which physical port the disconnected adapters have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
[hypervisor05]: PS C:\Users\adminsystem\Documents> Get-NetAdapterHardwareInfo | select Name, LocationInformationString | Sort LocationInformationString

Name       LocationInformationString
----       -------------------------
Ethernet 4 PCI bus 3, device 0, function 0
Ethernet 9 PCI bus 3, device 0, function 1
Ethernet 6 PCI bus 4, device 0, function 0
Ethernet 8 PCI bus 4, device 0, function 1
Ethernet 7 PCI-Bus 6, Gerät 0, Funktion 0
Ethernet 2 PCI-Bus 9, Gerät 0, Funktion 0
Ethernet   PCI-Bus 9, Gerät 0, Funktion 1
Ethernet 5 PCI-Bus 9, Gerät 0, Funktion 2
Ethernet 3 PCI-Bus 9, Gerät 0, Funktion 3
```

Basically the `LocationInformationString` Property which `Get-NetAdapterHardwareInfo` returns, tells you which Physical Port belongs to which Network adapter.

- PCI bus seems to be the NIC slot on the motherboard
- Device is the location number of slot on motherboard
- Function is the physical port we are looking for (starting from 0)

If you want the information in different properties than just in one string you could use this (source: [technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37427.identify-physical-port-in-multiple-ports-network-adapter-on-windows-servers-with-powershell.aspx))

```
Get-NetAdapterHardwareInfo | select Name, InterfaceDescription, DeviceType, Busnumber, Devicenumber, Functionnumber
```